# Usage of colors and background - Header and Footer | eCommerce

Tags: e-commerce, color-scheme, header, color-perception

Are there any key UX research references for the usage of colours on an ecommerce website? Looking for any research data so that we can make objective decisions. Our brand colour is a Deep orange and currently the website is painted with orange which can give someone sleepless nights. Any pointers will be great.

Comment: Not sure that you will be able to make objective decisions on something as subjective as colours (which is also context sensitive), but a good starting point for e-commerce related research might be the Baymard site: https://baymard.com/research

Comment: Couple of articles which may help https://www.toptal.com/designers/ux/color-in-ux, https://uxplanet.org/how-color-can-effect-emotion-ccab0431b1d

Comment: From my experience, you should probably stick to ADA compliancy (if you're in the US, not sure how it is other parts of the world) - ensure that anything passes contrast so that visually impaired people can actually read what you have. I've worked on brands their primary brand color is red, and it had nothing to do with food (supposedly red makes you more hungry?)

Answer (score 1):

Econsultancy did some up to date [market research on this topic](https://econsultancy.com/23-clever-uses-for-colour-in-ecommerce-ux/).

While subjective, the themes coming through in the analysis is that the use of colour is intrinsically linked to the brand values and audience. For example, [Crayola](https://www.crayola.com/) uses a vibrant fun colour scheme you would expect of a crayon manufacturer, alas not for an office stationary store.

More significantly however, use of colour is important for [communicating status](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/visibility-system-status/) and compelling users into action, one of nngroup's [ten heuristics](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/) for UI design.

> Definition: The visibility of system status refers to how well the
>   state of the system is conveyed to its users. Ideally, systems should
>   always keep users informed about what is going on, through appropriate
>   feedback within reasonable time.

Think about how colour can be used in ecommerce to communicate feedback and transparency, for example using a colour to draw attention to the shopping bag icon as it's updated with items, or using a colour to communicate that an item is out of stock. All of this helps give the customer adequate feedback and if this is balanced well with use of brand colours as described above it will increase customer trust in your brand.

Back to your "orange brand colour" case, in this scenario it would make sense to not overuse this so as to not distract and confuse customers in a purchase journey, where providing feedback is important to achieving their goals. Of course colour is not the only way of achieving this but something to bear in mind when setting out in a bold new direction for your branded storefront.